# Why is the Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path cut off when rotated, as if the shape's borders aren't rotated with the shape?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, rotation, shapes

Why is the Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path cut off when rotated, as if the shape's borders aren't rotated with the shape? I create AbsoluteLayout, then create several shapes and add them to AbsoluteLayout.Chidrens. When the shapes do not have rotation, everything is fine, and when there is, then the shapes is cropped as in the image.

Code example

```
AbsoluteLayout AL = new AbsoluteLayout();
RotateTransform RT = new RotateTransform { CenterX = SomeX, CenterY = SomeY, Angle = 20 };
EllipseGeometry CircleGeom = new EllipseGeometry { Center = new Point(SomeX, SomeY), RadiusX = 50, RadiusY = 50 };
Path CircleGeomPath = new Path { Data = CircleGeom, StrokeThickness = 1, Stroke = Color.Black, Fill = Color.White, RenderTransform = RT };
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(CircleGeomPath, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
AL.Children.Add(CircleGeomPath);

RectangleGeometry RectGeom = new RectangleGeometry { Rect = new Rect { X = SomeX, Y = SomeY - 25, Width = 150, Height = 50 } };
Path RectPath = new Path { Data = RectGeom, StrokeThickness = 1, Stroke = Color.Black, Fill = Color.White, RenderTransform = RT };
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(RectPath, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
AL.Children.Add(RectPath);
```

What needs to be done so that the shapes are rotated and not cut off?

[image example - shapes with and without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWDKv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried different layouts and angles with your code on my device. Finally, I think this problem is caused by the system which will set size of the view's area on Android. So when the view rotates, a part of it will be cut off when the part is out of range.

So you can set the path's heightrequest and weightrequest to give it a bigger size of area. Such as:

```
Path CircleGeomPath = new Path { Data = CircleGeom, StrokeThickness = 1, Stroke = Color.Black, Fill = Color.Blue, RenderTransform = RT,HeightRequest= 200,WidthRequest =400 };

Path RectPath = new Path { Data = RectGeom, StrokeThickness = 1, Stroke = Color.Black, Fill = Color.Blue, RenderTransform = RT, HeightRequest = 400, WidthRequest = 400 };
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar yesterday, using AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(SomePath, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 0, DrawAreaWidth, DrawAreaHeight));
So far I've settled on this option. It's a pity, of course, that the view's borders don't rotate automatically with the shape :)

Comment: What does the view's borders mean? The area's range of it? @dima121181

Comment: Yes, the area's range of it